# Eloquent Many-to-many with pivot sync with default values while preserving existing values

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Given the following many-to-many Relation, i am trying to synchronize newly added and removed `Users` for an `Item` while inserting an `Item`-based default value for new Pivot-table-entries and keeping the existing pivot values for `field`:

```php
<?php

class Item {
    protected $attributes = [
        'default_field' => false,
    ];

    public function users(): BelongsToMany
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class)->withPivot('field');
    }
}

class User {
    // ...
}
```

When using `$item->users()->sync([1,2,3])`, the default value will not be passed into the pivot table and when using `$item->users()->syncWithPivotValues([1,2,3], ['field' => $item->default_field]);` existing pivot values will be overwritten.

Is there a way to sync entries in a many-to-many relationship with additional values while preserving already existing pivot values?

For example if I have the following pivot table data before the sync:

| item_id | user_id | field |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | True |
| 1 | 2 | True |

Then trying to sync the users with ID 2 and 3 for item with ID 1

```php
<?php

$item->users()->sync([2,3]); // this doesn't set the default value from $item
```

And which should remove the user with ID 1 and add user with ID 3 and default value from $item:

| item_id | user_id | field |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | True |
| 1 | 3 | False |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you can use `attach()` instead

You can create an array as demonstrated below of users

```php
$item->users()->attach([
    1 => ['field' => $item->default_field],
    2 => ['field' => $item->default_field]
]);
```

or `syncWithoutDetaching()`

```php
$item->users()->syncWithoutDetaching([
    1 => ['field' => $item->default_field],
    2 => ['field' => $item->default_field]
])
```

Comment: Thanks, sadly both `attach()` and `syncWithoutDetaching()` will only add new entries and not remove not-needed ones. I updated my question for clarification of the expected behaviour in case it was not clear.

Comment: Well, you can use the `sync()` as I did for `attach()`, you will remove the not needed ones and add the new one with default value of each user based on `$item->default_field`, as you demonstrate in your QS  users with **ID: 2,3** will be added with the value of `$item->default_field` and **ID: 1** will be removed !

Comment: **but you can't keep the old values I don't think so there's a feature like that on Laravel YET**

Comment: Fair enough, using `sync()` and mapping the already existing values into it in addition to the default value solves this issue, thanks!

Comment: Glad that did it works for you !